# The "Is QA's job Only..." question should be moved

Tags: support

This question [Is QA's job only to perform Quality Assurance of developer's work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/132322/is-qas-job-only-to-perform-quality-assurance-of-developers-work) really should be moved to the Software Quality Assurance & Testing stackexchange.

It doesn't belong here. And would have a better chance to get an answer there.

Comment: As per "do not migrate crap" this question would need a pretty big clean-up, even before we consider if it would be on-topic there, which I'm not sure of.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for raising this.  It seems like there were a few answers submitted before the question was placed on hold, and there's good advice there.

I left a comment indicating that the OP can continue with this issue in SQA if they so wish.